# Adding a differential dc bias to a fully differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

How do I add dc bias to a fully differential amplifier? I cannot add it with Vocm or Vref pins because the receiver system also has a differential input and the offset common mode signal I add to the Vocm or Vref pins will be accepted and deleted.

In this case, should I add (DC bias /(2 x G)) to the non inverting terminal and -(DC bias /(2 x G)) to the inverting pin for the dc bias I want to add?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish by adding DC bias? Are you trying to offset the _output_?

Comment: I need to make cold junction compensation for the thermocouple  signal conditioner. If it had been single ended, this problem would not have occurred and I could have made a summing  configuration. However, there is a differential input adc in the target system.

Comment: That's why I use a differential output instrumentation amplifier to process the thermocouple signal. If you amplify the signal using a single-ended opamp and use a fully differential amplifier at the output, the cost will increase. At the same time, the input offset will also increase. For resistance inequalities, I can use a differential output difference amplifier (I can use the resistors included in the waffer, but I am not sure if there is a differential output difference amplifier).

Comment: Could you make a table, with some sample inputs, and the expected outputs for those inputs? I have a guess as to what you want, but I would like to confirm. For example, I think if the inputs are equal, you want the outputs to be +Voff and -Voff. If the inputs are 1 mV and -1 mV you want the outputs to be 1 mV*G + Voff and -1 mV*G - Voff. Is that correct? Please put this kind of information in your question, so new readers don't need to read all the comments to get all the information.